# How do I set LaTeX to use AMS Euler for text and maths?

Tags: fonts

How do you setup LaTeX to use Euler for displaying maths? I can't figure out how to do it!

Edit: I thought it'd work by adding `amsfonts` to the document and specifying an option. I'll try out my document with the `euler` or `vmeuler` packages and see which's better.

Comment: There is no Euler text font. Are you referring to Palatino, as text font?

Answer (score 2):

as my crystal ball is in the dishwasher today, it would be good to have a [minimal working example](http://goo.gl/5XLQU) (showing what you've tried so far) and some more details on the situation you're in. For example, you may need to do different things in order to load a font depending on what TeX engine you're using.

For ordinary pdfTeX, you'd do the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
lorem ipsum
\begin{equation}
  a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

...while with LuaTeX, you'll need something like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
lorem ipsum
\begin{equation}
  a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]