# How to Recover my Bold SF Fonts

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I was inspired by this link to try EulerVM with tgpagella packages:

[How do I set LaTeX to use AMS Euler for text and maths?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116351/how-do-i-set-latex-to-use-ams-euler-for-text-and-maths)

But when this is used with `\documentclass{scrbook}`, it seems that my bold-faced sans serif fonts are overwritten. Not only with the sections and subsections and whatnot, but in other areas that I have designated to have a bold sans serif font such as my enumi counters.

Can someone help me bring the sans serif bold back in computer modern but with a fully functioning use of EulerVM with `tgpagella` packages?

I apologize in advance if I am not properly following conventions here.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{microtype}

\def\theenumi{\textsf{\textbf{\arabic{enumi}}}}
\def\theenumii{\textsf{\textbf{\alph{enumii}}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\section{A Section}



\subsection{A Subsection}

Some numbers

\begin{enumerate}
\item The item should be bold sans.

\item It seems that they are being over written somewhere

\item I also get this: Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/b/n' undefined
(Font)  using `T1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 14.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am such a novice? Can some one edit my comment into a nice MWE box? My humble apologies.

Comment: I reverted your last edit: it's better to have the code rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 8):

The `tgpagella` package does

```
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
```

where the original value is `bx`. Since the standard Computer Modern Sans font don't know of a `b` series, but only a `bx` series, the internal substitution mechanism chooses medium series.

You can correct this in two ways.

1. Load `lmodern` before `tgpagella`, because the Latin Modern Sans fonts know about a `b` series
2. Do `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}` after loading `tgpagella`.

The fonts you get are slightly different. Take your pick. In the code below I load only the font packages, add the others you need.

### Method 1

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

### Method 2

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{microtype}
```